# Excel VBA Paste entire row from array of arrays into table

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I have an array of arrays. Its dimensions can be summed like this:
**varZaznamyNove(0)(1 to 2, 1 to 20)** as shown in the picture.

I want to take an entire row and put the data from that row into an Excel table. For example:
`Range(objListRowBytoveDomyNovy.Range(1, 1), objListRowBytoveDomyNovy.Range(1, 20)) = varZaznamyNove(0)(intPorovnavanyZaznamNovy)`

When I attempt to run the line, I get an error:

> Run time error 9: Subscript out of range.

**How can I put entire row from a jagged array, without looping through all of its columns, into an excel table?**

Variables used are dimensioned as follows:
`objListRowBytoveDomyNovy as lisrow`
`intPorovnavanyZaznamNovy as integer`
`varZaznamyNove(0) as variant`

**Note:**
I don't get an error, when I add second index to the right side of the line, e.g.:
`Range(objListRowBytoveDomyNovy.Range(1, 1), objListRowBytoveDomyNovy.Range(1, 20)) = varZaznamyNove(0)(intPorovnavanyZaznamNovy,1)`
but this only pust first column into all of the table columns. That is not desired.

Example of the data is shown in picture. Just to show what I work with (dummy data).

[image: Example of the data]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
Range(objListRowBytoveDomyNovy.Range(1, 1), objListRowBytoveDomyNovy.Range(1, 20)).Value = Application.Index(varZaznamyNove(0), intPorovnavanyZaznamNovy, 0)
```

Comment: Thank you very much! I love plain and simple solutions. [Nice article about the topic](https://usefulgyaan.wordpress.com/2013/06/12/vba-trick-of-the-week-slicing-an-array-without-loop-application-index/)